# is there a light(er) weight framework for ruby, like web.py for python?

Tags: python, ruby

I've recently been seeing more and more about lighter and lighter weight web frameworks - mainly for python (flask, web.py) .

I'm just curious if there's anything similar for ruby. I haven't found anything in my travels yet but maybe i'm not travelling in the right places.

Comment: Sinatra makes web.py look bloated :-) http://www.sinatrarb.com/

Comment: -1.  This seems way too easy to google for.  I just searched for *ruby web frameworks*.  The [second link](http://vemod.net/list-of-ruby-web-frameworks) is a pretty good list.

Comment: i don't need a long list. i just need a couple of frameworks to actually look into. Someone with experience with a particular web framework would be useful.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should use [Sinatra](http://www.sinatrarb.com/) if you want a light weight ruby web framework.

Answer (score 3):

Check out [Grape](https://github.com/intridea/grape) if you're looking to build a *REST-like API*. [Here's](http://armoredcode.com/blog/build-an-api-for-fun-with-grape/) a nice primer.

Answer (score 0):

[Camping](https://camping.github.io/camping.io/) is good, despite being slightly... special.  [Ramaze](http://ramaze.net/) can be *very* lightweight. Oh, and I should add that depending on your definition of lightweight, you *can* build [lightweight apps in Rails](https://gist.github.com/1942658).